# React native serial port

Tags: android, react-native, serial-port, usb

I have problem with usb serial port on android with react native.
Here is my App.jsx code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import SerialPort from 'react-native-serialport';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {

    SerialPort.read((data) => {
      console.log('Received data:', data);
    });

    return () => {
      SerialPort.close();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Serial Reader</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

if i run it on android it shows error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tasks'.
> Could not create task ':react-native-usb-serialport:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
   > In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
```

I tried with so many serial port packages but i didnt found anything what working

Comment: Can you share your android/build.gradle file please

Answer (score 0):

in your project, nodemodules->react-native-serialport-> android-> build.gradle filechange the compileSdkVersion to 30.. It is 28 or 29 default.. that worked for me

Comment: That seems like a good solution. But as soon as you reinstall node_modules you will loose the change and will have the problem agains. I recommend making a patch with `patch-package` https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package), so that it keeps working if you reintstall your node modules